# JavaScript - Accessing variables from another function

Tags: javascript, html

I´m new to StackOverflow, so if I make a mistake, please be lenient with me.

I have a problem. When I am trying to access to a variable from another function, it results "null".

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var latitude = 0;
    var longitude = 0;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("geocode").value;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, 
    function getCoordinates(results, status) {
        //if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
             latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
             longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

        } 
    //}
    );
    var uluru = {lat: latitude, 
    lng: longitude};
    var map = new google.maps.Map
    (document.getElementById('map'), 
    {
      center: uluru,
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the connection with php and html? Please remove those tags.

Comment: What's the question again?   What line are we talking about?

Comment: Which variable is getting set to null?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware ok, I will do that.

Comment: @Keith I want to get latitude and longitude from function getCoordinates() in the var uluru

Comment: @Abhishek lat and long if i dont create them at the beginning

Comment: Then the answers given are your problem, you can't access variables from an asynchronous function synchronously.  The geocode function uses a callback, as soon as you see these it's normally an asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

latitude and longitude for `uluru` are fully populated in the geocoding callback function which is not necessarily going to make them available when the function loads so instead you could use the callback to set the map center when those values are available.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    var latitude = 0;
    var longitude = 0;
    var uluru = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude };

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("geocode").value;

    geocoder.geocode({'address':address}, function getCoordinates( results, status ) {
        if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

            map.setCenter( new google.maps.LatLng( latitude,longitude ) ;
        } 
    });

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: uluru,
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple example of accessing variables:

```
<script>
var a = 10;
var c;

function aa() {
  document.write("func aa ");
  var b = 20;
  c = b;
  document.write(a + b);
}

function bb() {
  document.write("func bb ");
  document.write(c);
}

aa();
document.write(" ");
bb();
```

Answer (score 0):

From doc of [Google Geocoding Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

> Accessing the Geocoding service is asynchronous

This means that your function is called after the inizialization of `uluru` object.

You should inizialize the map and `uluru` object inside the function `getCoordinates`